# Save an array of booleans using Shared preference

Tags: java, android, arrays, sharedpreferences

I have a long list of booleans which i want to save In my app using shared preference, so that i can save the state of a number of checkboxes.  i have tried a few approaches now, and am now so sick of the same code, that im even willing to ask for help.

I would post my code, but there is so much greentext and redundant information that i dotn think its worth it.  But if it helps.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    // second attempt to hold the values
    private SharedPreferences keyValues;
    private int totalLength;

    private String[] parentList = { "Bedding", "Bedroom Items", "Clothing",
            "Bags", "Stationary", "Documents", "Electronics", "Toiletries",
            "Kitchen Items" };

    // used to retain our checklist values, which for some reason dont stick.
    private boolean[] checkState;

    // multidimensional array for storing the child Strings
    private String[][] childList = {
            { "Single/Double sheets", "Single/Double duvet + Covers",
                    "Pillows + Pillow cases" },
            { "Alarm Clock", "Posters", "Door Wedge", "Lamp", "Small Bin",
                    "Hamper Basket" },
            { "Casual Clothes, i.e T shirts, jeans, hoodies",
                    "Smart clothing for interviews and presentations",
                    "Warm Clothing (especially for newcastle)",
                    "'Party Clothes' clothes for going out",
                    "Underwear and socks", "pyjamas", "Comfortable shoes",
                    "Sports trainers", "Swimwear" },
            { "Everyday bag/backpack", "Gym bag", "Clear Pencil Case",
                    "Purse/Wallet", "Watch" },
            { "Pins", "A4 Notebooks", "Pens/Pencils", "Highlighters", "Ruler",
                    "Rubber", "Selotape", "Hole Puncher", "A4 Binders",
                    "Calculater", "Calender" },
            { "Passport photos", "Passport",
                    "Driving License (some form of id)", "Your NI Card",
                    "Insurance Documents", "NHS Medical Card",
                    "Insurance documents", "Letter of Acceptance",
                    "Scholarship/bursury letters",
                    "Rail Card(if you have one)", "C.V" },
            { "Laptop+Charger", "Mouse", "Phone + Charger", "Ethernet Cables",
                    "USB memory stick", "Headphones", "Digital Camera",
                    "MP3 Player" },
            { "Shampoo", "Razors", "Toothbrush and toothpaste",
                    "Make-up/remover", "HairBrush",
                    "Condoms or other protection!!!" },
            { "Frying Pan", "Wok", "Tin Opener", "Bottle opener", "Glasses",
                    "Cheese Grater", "Knives", "Chopping Board", "Scissors",
                    "Tea Towels", "Tupperware", "Cling Film", "Cutlery",
                    "Crockery" } };


    public ExpListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        int [] lengths = new int [childList.length];

        for (int i=0;i<childList.length;i++){
             lengths[i] = childList[i].length;
             totalLength=totalLength+ lengths[i];
        }
        // initialised check
                checkState = new boolean[totalLength];

    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

        return childPosition;
    }

    //
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


    public void loadPrefs(){

        //where i want to put code to load during my constructor

    }


    public static boolean  savePrefs(){

        //where i want to put code to commit data to storage


        }


    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;
        //final int mChildPosition = childPosition;

        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(context);
        //checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        for (int i=0;i<totalLength;i++){
            checkState[i]= checkbox.isChecked();

        }

        /*if (checkState.containsKey(mGroupPosition)) {
            boolean getChecked[] = checkState.get(mGroupPosition);
            checkbox.setChecked(getChecked[mChildPosition]);
        } else {
            boolean getChecked[] = new boolean[getChildrenCount(mGroupPosition)];
            checkState.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
            checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }
        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {

                    boolean getChecked[] = checkState.get(mGroupPosition);
                    getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                    checkState.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

                } else {

                    boolean getChecked[] = checkState.get(mGroupPosition);
                    getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                    checkState.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
                }

            }
        });*/

        checkbox.setText(childList[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        checkbox.setPadding(40, 0, 0, 0);

        //

        return checkbox;
    }

    // returns the number of children you are having.

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childList[groupPosition].length;
    }

    // returns the number of parents you have.
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return parentList.length;
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView text = new TextView(context);
        text.setText(parentList[groupPosition]);
        text.setPadding(40, 0, 0, 0);
        return text;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: SharedPreferences is key/value paired, there isnt anything to hold multiple keys with multiple values

Comment: I havent found trace of using SharedPreference in your code. What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: You can do it by storing a String in SharedPreferences. I am writing a solution.

Comment: @user3307142 what do you mean explain? there is nothing to explain, you cannot store an array of keys with an array of values if that is what you are trying to accomplish. each key needs to be its own preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save an array of booleans to memory, I suggest you build a string from the booleans as follows:

**Initialization**

```
private boolean[] checkState;
private Editor mEditPrefs;
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
//initialize checkState array and mEditPrefs and mPreferences
```

**Save the array**

```
String save = "";
for (int n = 0; n < checkState.length; n++) {
    if (checkState[n] != null) {
                if(checkState[n]) {
                    save = save + "true" + "|$|SEPARATOR|$|";
                } else {
                    save = save + "false" + "|$|SEPARATOR|$|";
                }
    }
}
mEditPrefs.putString("memory", save);
mEditPrefs.commit();
```

**Get the Array**

```
String mem = mPreferences.getString("memory", "");
mEditPrefs.putString("memory", "");
String[] array = getArray(mem); //see below for the getArray() method
checkState = new boolean[array.length];
for(int n = 0; n < array.length; n++){
    if(array[n].equals("true"){
        checkState[n] = true;
    } else {
        checkState[n] = false;
    }
}
```

**the getArray() method**

```
public static String[] getArray(String input) {
    return input.split("\\|\\$\\|SEPARATOR\\|\\$\\|");
}
```

This isn't an elegent solution, but SharedPreferences doesn't support storing arrays, so the only way to store an array is to make a long string separated by a discernible separator (in this case |$|SEPARATOR|$| ) that won't be confused with the data you are storing. Also, since there's no way to store arrays, I converted the booleans to strings before storing them and then I retrieve them from memory and detect if it is "true" or "false" and set the checkState array accordingly.

Hope this helped. I use a very similar process for storing an array of URLs and it works perfectly.

Alternatively you could use an SQLiteDatabase to store your array, but that might be a little too much work just to store some booleans.

EDIT: Originally I thought that [toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Boolean.html#toString%28%29) would work on a boolean, but apparently not on an array.

Comment: also, i started off with an sql, but apparently its bad to do for an app, when youre dealing with data that is only changed by the user.  thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, SQL isn't really designed to store arrays, it's more for storing a lot of data (like list of contacts) and retrieving it often and adding to it, whereas you just want to save some data for the next launch. Also, thanks for putting me over 1,000 reputation :)

Comment: no problem, just got round to implementing your code by the way, its throwing me a couple of errors so  changed a couple of things.

Comment: @user3307142 what sort of errors? I haven't actually compiled this specific code so I'm not surprised I made a mistake or two.

Comment: I see I had an incorrectly named string in the first block of code.

Comment: also, you cant use toString on a boolean

Comment: I'll update that. I specifically looked it up and thought it said you could use to string, guess I'm wrong.

Comment: no problem man, i still cant solve this problem, i thought i was pretty good at android java until this stuff came alone and kicked me in the nuts. thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @user3307142 I updated the answer with a replacement for toString(), basically just an if statement checking whether to put "true" or "false into the string. If it doesn't work please tell me.